# Turning secondary keys into primary keys in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas Dataframe: Turning secondary keys into primary keys in Python

I would like to pass the secondary keys of this plot as primary key. Currently, the primary key is 'ustar' but I want 'time', 'latitude' and 'longitude' to be the primary keys. How do I do this?

```
ustar = ds['ustar'].to_dataframe()
print(ustar)
```

[image: print(ustar)]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Transpose? `ds.T`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not the solution to my problem. I would like to put 'ustar' at the same level as 'time', 'longitude' and 'latitude' in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to put 'ustar' at the same level as 'time', 'longitude' and 'latitude' in the dataframe

I think you want to [reset your index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
ds = ds.reset_index()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer, it's exactly what I needed!